# Branding downloaded apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

i have download an app from the sharepoint app store, an rss feed, i now want to design it with my custom css. Is it possible?

I saw the css was in the url:
 https://mysiteURL-45ff9e9be1ba36.sharepoint.com/AmexusRSSNews/Content/App.css

But i couldnt find it in sharepoint designer, is it possible to style downloaded apps?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't - it is up to the App publisher.

And! All serious SharePoint App publishers SHOULD conform to the guidelines and use the native features for branding their apps...

Comment: Guidelines can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220046(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Tack för info, jag får väll använda jquery då